# CORS response not received on different computers

Tags: javascript, cors

This is my first question on SO, but you have all helped me enormously in the past from existing posts - so thank you!

I am working on a Web/Database system using localhost through Xampp, but need to backup sql file to my one&one online server. I am using CORS for cross-domain with js to make the backup and it works on my PC, but not my clients. The request onload works for us both, as the files are saved, but my client does not receive the response message to confirm it has saved!! Anyone know why this might be - we are both running IE9 and same xampp versions.
Code I am using for CORS request is:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('POST', "http://www.mysite/Backups", true);
request.onload = function()
{
  if (request.status === 200) 
  { //response functions here}
  request.send("Content="+backupContent);
}
```

Hope this is in the correct question format - its my first time remember!

Answer (score 0):

I had a year ago a really similar problem with IE. Your client is using IE, that means they are quite big and serious, so I bet they also have specific settings for IE security.

Go to your IE security preferences and restrict everything you can - I cannot tell you exactly the name of the property, I have no explorer anymore, but with this you can reproduce this behaviour.

How to solve the issue? Usually they don't agree on changing their security settings, so the only way that worked for me is using JSONP instead of CORS. I know: not modern, uglly... But that works.

This is just a guess, I trust that everything is done correctly on your side.